# Determine whether type is singleton via reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

How can I find out whether a type is a singleton or not?

```
case object Foo
case class Bar(i: Int)

def isSingleton[A](implicit t: reflect.ClassTag[A]): Boolean = ???

assert( isSingleton[Foo.type])
assert(!isSingleton[Bar     ])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need a `ClassTag` (`<:<` is deprecated in `ClassTag`)? If not, then it works this way:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def isSingleton[A : TypeTag] = typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[Singleton]
isSingleton: [A](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Boolean

scala> isSingleton[Foo.type]
res5: Boolean = true

scala> isSingleton[Bar]
res6: Boolean = false
```

Comment: No, `TypeTag` is fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking in the wrong place or what, but I cannot find a type in the Scala API docs named `Singleton`. Where does it reside?

Comment: @RandallSchulz: It is one of Scalas "magic" types. It only exists in the compiler...

Comment: I see. I guess it's an oversight, then, 'cause other "synthetic" types have ScalaDoc entries even though they're not derived from code that actually gets compiled into the Scala Standard Library.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add another possibility which is useful when you are on the level of `Symbol` (e.g. going down the sub types of type):

```
def isSingleton[A: TypeTag]: Boolean = typeOf[A].typeSymbol.isModuleClass
```